# How to connect WiFi with known SSID and password via adb or shell command

Tags: android, android-wifi

I am working on an Android auto-test program with UI Automator, Python, and shell. It is pretty complex to connect to WiFi via UI Automator so I am looking for a new way to connect to WiFi with the known SSID password via adb, shell or Python method.

Comment: I presume the device is NOT rooted?

Comment: GOT IT,so much thanks for your kindly help. ^_^

Comment: In that case, you should describe your solution. That way this question would be helpful for others with the same issue.